# strtotime days of the week not displaying in french

Tags: php, strtotime

My code will not output days of the week in French. Note: I have also tried to translate the days of the week within the code with the same results (output in English only).

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra');
$today = strtotime('Saturday 14:00');
$tomorrow = strtotime('Saturday 14:00');

$friday = strtotime('Friday 14:00');
$sunday = strtotime('Sunday 24:00');

$now = time();

if($now < $friday && $now > $sunday)
{

    $timeLeft = ($now > $today ? $tomorrow : $today) - $now;

    $hoursLeft = gmdate("G", $timeLeft);
    $minutesLeft = gmdate("i", $timeLeft);
    $secondsLeft = gmdate("s", $timeLeft);

    if($hoursLeft > 0)
    {
        echo $hoursLeft . ' heur';

        if($minutesLeft > 0)
        {
            echo ' et ' . $minutesLeft . ' minutes';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo $minutesLeft . ' minutes et ' . $secondsLeft . ' seconde ';
    }
}
else

$date = date("l\, F j", strtotime("tomorrow"));

$day = date('l', strtotime('today'));

if ($day == 'Friday')
{
    if($now > strtotime('Friday 14:00'))
    {
        echo date('l, F j', strtotime('Tuesday'));
    }
    elseif($now < strtotime('Friday 14:00'))
    {
        echo date('l, F j', strtotime('Monday'));
    }
}
elseif ($day == 'Saturday' || $day == 'Sunday')
{
    echo date('l, F j', strtotime('Tuesday'));
}
```

However if I use this basic code on it's own outside of the above it displays properly:

```
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra'); 
echo (strftime("%A %d %B"));
```

How do I get the first block to output in French only?

Comment: Off topic but why are your `$today` and `$tomorrow` same?

Comment: The original code is longer with elaborate weekend rules, I shortened it to keep it concise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`date()`](http://www.php.net/date) is not location-aware, you should use [`strftime()`](http://www.php.net/strftime) for that... And it accepts a second `$timestamp` argument exactly as `date()`. Just replace all `date()` occurrences with `strftime()` equivalent and you'll get what you want.

So...

Replace:

```
$date = date("l\, F j", strtotime("tomorrow"));
```

With:

```
$date = strftime('%A, %B %e', strtotime('tomorrow'));
```

Replace:

```
$day = date('l', strtotime('today'));
```

With:

```
$day = strftime('%A', strtotime('today'));
```

Replace:

```
    echo date('l, F j', strtotime('Tuesday'));
```

With:

```
    echo strftime('%A, %B %e', strtotime('Tuesday'));
```

Replace:

```
    echo date('l, F j', strtotime('Monday'));
```

With:

```
    echo strftime('%A, %B %e', strtotime('Monday'));
```

Replace:

```
echo date('l, F j', strtotime('Tuesday'));
```

With:

```
echo strftime('%A, %B %e', strtotime('Tuesday'));
```

And that's all! :)

Comment: Thank you :) Would bump you up, but don't have enough street cred!

Comment: @sr_1436048 You're welcome! You could accept the answer anyway, just click on the checkmark icon next to the answer! It'll increase your reputation by +2 and when you reach 15 you'll be able to vote up! :)

Comment: @sr_1436048 Thank you! I'm glad I was able to help you! :)